# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named error python 3.8.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, pynacl

8.2

When I install a new module with `pip install PyNaCl` it says it downloaded successfully, then I check with `pip list` and its there and when I run my python code I get **"No Module Named "PyNaCl"** error. It's not from the module because I tried with different ones and I get the same error.

Comment: You likely have more than 1 python installation.  Try `pip3.8 install ...`

Comment: @HymnsForDisco I uninstalled all of them yesterday and i have only the 3.8.2 and I tried and I get `Requirement already satisfied: pynacl in c:\python38\lib\site-packages (1.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\python38\lib\site-packages (from pynacl) (1.14.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.4.1 in c:\python38\lib\site-packages (from pynacl) (1.14.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in c:\python38\lib\site-packages (from cffi>=1.4.1->pynacl) (2.19)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because while the pypi package is called `PyNaCl`, the actual library is called `nacl`, [as can be seen in the official documentation](https://pynacl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/hash/).

Answer (score 0):

PyNaCl's runtime module name is `nacl`, so it must be imported by `import nacl`.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by downloading and installing the python 3.8.2 package [from here](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-382/)

I noticed in my text editor that the file I was trying to import was displaying 3.8.0